# Unable to understand "&" in this code. I am very beginner to php. Kindly let me know could any one solve it?

Tags: php

Unable to understand `&`in this code. I am very beginner to php. Kindly let me know could any one solve it?

```
  $a = 1;
  $b = &$a;
  $a =5&$b; 
  echo $a; 
  exit();
```

Comment: where you get like this?

Comment: Never saw this. What context?

Comment: This is a good reference: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3737139/reference-what-does-this-symbol-mean-in-php

Comment: Do you need further help on this?

Answer (score 4):

In this context, the `&` is a bitwise `and` ([bitwise operators](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php)).

```
$a = 1;     // the var a is now 1
$b = &$a;   // the var b is now the var a (not the int 1)
$a =5&$b;   // 5 & $b ( 1 = 0001) = ( 1 = 0001) & ( 5 = 0101)
echo $a;    // prints 1
exit();
```

What this will do is getting the bit value of the numbers (1 = 0001 and 5 = 0101) and apply an and operation.

Some examples to understand other values in this context:

```
( 1 = 0001) = ( 1 = 0001) & ( 1 = 0001)
( 0 = 0000) = ( 1 = 0001) & ( 2 = 0010)
( 1 = 0001) = ( 1 = 0001) & ( 3 = 0011)
( 0 = 0000) = ( 1 = 0001) & ( 4 = 0100)
( 1 = 0001) = ( 1 = 0001) & ( 5 = 0101)
```

**Update:** as OP asked, I will try to explain further:

A bitwise `AND` operator will take two equal-length binary representations and perform a logical `AND`.

A logical `AND` will take two operands and is `true` if and only if all of its operands are `true`.

So e.g.:

```
operand 1    operand 2    result
true         true         true
false        true         false
true         false        false
false        false        false
```

Note that `true = 1` and `false = 0`.

So to explain what it's gonna do in your explicit case (1 & 5):

- Get the binary representations of `1` (it's `0001`) and `5` (it's `0101`).
- Perform a logical `AND` (from right to left):

  - 1 & 1 = 1 (`true`)
  - 1 & 0 = 0 (`false`)
  - 0 & 1 = 0 (`false`)
  - 0 & 0 = 0 (`false`)

So the result is `0001` (binary representation of `1`).